# is there any Ruby or Rails reporting tools based on customizable templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reporting

I am looking for a report generator done in ruby or rails which allow user to define a template first then fetch the data into the template.

I have been looking through "The Ruby Box: reporting section" (https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting.html)

There are two reporting tools are similar to what I am look for:

[Thin Reports](http://www.thinreports.org/):
It is really good. You download a template editor then you define your own report template then by combine the thinreports gems you can get SVG or PDF report out of your application.

[ODF Report](https://github.com/sandrods/odf-report):
It uses ODF file as template which can be edit by OpenOffice and MS Word 2010. Then You get your report out.

However, both of them not have the ability to draw charts.
Does anyone know any reporting tools does similar job to these two but also be able to draw charts within the report?

The minimum requirements are:

1. Able to create customizable templates. eg. design layout, set font size, color, embed images etc.
2. Able to draw tables, charts.
3. Template could be ODT or excel or tif or any other common file.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PeterPeng.

> The following is message by the machine translation, so I'm sorry if you may be unable to understand...

I am developer of ThinReports.

In the newest ThinReports, it is possible to embed Graf as a picture.
The following is a sample using GoogleChart API.

[ThinReports Example: Embed a graph using the GoogleChartAPI](http://osc.matsukei.net/projects/thinreports/wiki/Example_GoogleChartAPI%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%82%92%E5%9F%8B%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80)

In addition, using such images to create a [Gruff](http://nubyonrails.com/pages/gruff), can be embedded as follows:

```
page.item(:image_block).src('/path/to/any.png')
page.item(:image_block).src(<Image Data>)
```

I hope helpful.